# CiviCRM_API3_Exception: Expected one CustomField but found 0 in civicrm_api3() (line 45 of sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php)

Tags: custom-fields, api, error

I was cleaning up some extra custom fields in our DB. ONe of these , though it was disabled did not stop displaying in the contact profile. So I clicked to delete it.

I then got this error when I tried to do anything in Civi:

```
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: Expected one CustomField but found 0 in civicrm_api3() (line 45 of /var/www/crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php).
```

I tried commenting out the offending code in api.php, which got me past the error, but produced a whole bunch more warnings.

I saw in the table - `civicrm_custom_field`, that the record for the field that I tried to delete was still there. I manually deleted it but that did not help.

IN this situation I can;t get into CiviCRM at all to turn on backtrace or any other logging.

Really and truly stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's existance is cached - try truncating civicrm_cache and  / or calling the System.flush api

Comment: I truncated civicrm_cache. BUt that didn't help

Comment: it's worth jumping into chat.civicrm.org when you are about because this sort of issue is usually better with a bit more back & forth.

There are probably backtraces in your ConfigAndLog directory - for drupal you would usually find them in sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog